# Is there any fallback function in smart contract similar to Ethereum?

Tags: smart-contract, wasm-api

In example dice at contracts directory, alice/bob should set permission to dice account for transferring EOS token from alice/bob to dice.

```
  alice                        dice contract       eosio.token contract
---------                      -------------        -------------------
    | set permission to dice       |                         |
    |                              |                         |
    |   offerbet(some eos)         |                         |
    |----------------------------->|  transfer(alice->dice)  |
    |                              |------------------------>|
    |                              |                         |
```

To play this game, alice/bob should grant privilege to dice for transferring EOS from alice/bob to dice.

Can alice/bob can transfer EOS to dice account directly and once dice can be triggered some action like fallback funciton in Ethereum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dice contract, as implemented, does not follow best practices. A better example is the exchange contract (also located in contracts folder) which has the user transfer funds to the exchange.